# Sorting the float data in the Array of dictionary in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, sorting, nsmutablearray, nsmutabledictionary

I am having the array of Dictionary and it's in the formats of,

```
 resultsArray = { 

id = 1;
name = test;
distance = 11.5;

id = 2;
name = test1;
distance = 0.5;

id = 3;
name = test2;
distance = 2.5;

id = 4;
name = test4;
distance = 1.5;
```

}

I want to sort the array using the distance key and my distance in the float type. So how can i sort the array using distance is in the ascending order?.

So i am expecting the results like this,

```
resultsArray = { 

id = 2;
name = test1;
distance = 0.5;

id = 4;
name = test4;
distance = 1.5;

id = 3;
name = test2;
distance = 2.5;

id = 1;
name = test;
distance = 11.5;

}
```

Please help me out.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NSArray *sortedArray = [resultsArray sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"distance" ascending:YES]]];
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer i have tried that but still having same issues so please help me out

Comment: Strange. I did a test to confirm my answer and it worked. Post your code.

Answer (score 0):

```
[resultArray sortUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id obj1, id obj2) {
    return [[obj1 objectForKey:@"distance"] compare:[obj2 objectForKey:@"distance"]];
}];
```

Answer (score 0):

And one more solution:

```
@interface NSDictionary(sortingByDistance)
-(NSComparisonResult) compareByDistance:(NSDictionary*)dict;
@end
@implementation NSDictionary(sortingByDistance)
-(NSComparisonResult) compareByDistance:(NSDictionary*)dict {
    return [[self objectForKey:@"distance"] compare:[dict objectForKey:@"distance"]];
}
@end
```

Now to sort array you can use `sortUsingSelector` method:

```
[resultArray sortUsingSelector:@selector(compareByDistance:)];
```